# shape of passed values x implies y with numpy.ndarray values in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm running into issues using DataFrame.apply with two arguments with a dataframe containing numpy.ndarray. The function itself is rather simple and outputs a numpy.ndarray:

```
def get_opponent_choice(choice,outcome):
    opp_choice = np.zeros_like(choice)
    opp_choice[outcome > 0] = choice[outcome > 0]
    opp_choice[outcome < 0] = 1 - choice[outcome < 0]

    return opp_choice

get_opponent_choice(df['dir_choice'].loc[0],df['outcomes'].loc[0])
df.apply(lambda x : get_opponent_choice(x['dir_choice'],x['outcomes']),axis=1)
```

Running a single test iteration works, however using the apply function gets me into trouble with:

```
Shape of passed values is (343, 54), indices imply (343, 9)
```

Ideally I'd like to output the data into a new column df['dir_opp'] containing numpy.ndarray data-type matching the shape of the input arrays (which varies across rows)

As requested,  each row displayed has arrays of different sizes but remains the same across columns: 
[DataFrame relevant columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zdaf.png)

Toy example to emulate the problem, running the df.apply function will generate the same errors:

```
toy_dict = []
toy_dict.append({'dir_choice' : np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]), 'outcomes' : np.array([1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1])})
toy_dict.append({'dir_choice' : np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]), 'outcomes' : np.array([1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1])})
toy_dict.append({'dir_choice' : np.array([0, 0, 1]), 'outcomes' : np.array([-1, -1, -1])})
toy_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(toy_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of testing with array values with the same size, I'm beginning to think array datatypes aren't the ideal input/output for DataFrame.apply - although I would love to be proved wrong.

Using a loop to create a second dataframe to join seems to work fine:

```
def get_opponent_choice(choice,outcome):
    opp_choice = np.zeros_like(choice)
    opp_choice[outcome > 0] = choice[outcome > 0]
    opp_choice[outcome < 0] = 1 - choice[outcome < 0]

    return opp_choice

join_dict = []  
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    join_dict.append({'opp_dir' : \
    get_opponent_choice(row[0],row[1])})

df.join(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(join_dict))
```

Comment: They are not the ideal types to store in a dataframe, it's common knowledge.